# Фильтр записей Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, filter, acf

Всем привет.

Дано http://cq94135.tmweb.ru/ustanovka-avtosignalizatsij/

фильтр http://joxi.ru/KAgePKzCgVRjVm

есть вывод записей ниже

вся логика набрана на advanced custom fields

вот код формы

```
 <div class="order-filter col-md-8" style="font-size:12px;text-align: right;color: #999;margin: 10px 0;">
            <p><a href=""><i class="fa fa-th"></i></a>&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href=""><i class="fa fa-arrows-v"></i></i></a>&nbsp;&nbsp;
            Показать: 
            <span style="color: #000">
            <select name="view" id="view">
                <option value="all">Все товары</option>
                <option value="16">По 16 шт.</option>
            </select>
            </span> Сортировка: 
            <span style="color: #000">
            <select name="sort" id="sort">
                <option value="pricehi">По цене по возрастанию</option>
                <option value="pricedown">По цене по убыванию</option>
            </select>
            </p>
            </div>
```

вот код вывода

```
<?php if ($fields->cat_id): ?>
                    <?php
                    $posts = get_posts(array('category' => $fields->cat_id));
                    //print_array($posts);
                    if ($posts):
                        foreach ($posts AS $p):
                            $f = (object)get_fields($p->ID);
                            //print_array($f);
                            ?>

                            <div class="single_tov box-shadow" price="<?php get_field('new_price'); ?>">
                                <div class="tags">
                                    <?php if($f->gift): ?>
                                    <img src="<?= get_template_directory_uri() ?>/img/tag_gift.png" alt="">
                                    <?php endif; ?>
                                </div>
                                <div class="foto_tov">
                                    <a href="<?= get_permalink($p->ID) ?>"><img src="<?= WP_img_resize($f->slider[0]['url'], 134, 130, true) ?>" alt=""></a>
                                </div>
                                <a href="<?= get_permalink($p->ID) ?>" class="prod_name">

                                    <?php echo get_the_title($p->ID); ?>
                                </a>
                                <div class="prod_desc">
                                    <?= $f->short_desc ?>
                                </div>
                                <div class="price_wrap clearfix">
                                    <?php if ($f->price && $f->old_price):
                                        $old_price = explode(' ', $f->old_price);
                                        $new_price = explode(' ', $f->price);
                                        ?>
                                        <div class="old_price">
                                            <span><?= number_format(@$old_price[0], 0, ',', ' ') ?></span><?= @$old_price[1] ? $old_price[1]  : 'руб.'?>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="price">
                                            <span><?= number_format(@$new_price[0], 0, ',', ' ') ?></span><?= @$new_price[1] ? $new_price[1] : 'руб.' ?>
                                        </div>
                                    <?php endif; ?>
                                    <?php if ($f->price && !$f->old_price):
                                        $new_price = explode(' ', $f->old_price);
                                        ?>
                                        <div class="price">
                                            <span><?= number_format($new_price[0], 0, ',', ' ') ?></span> <?= $new_price[1] ? $new_price[1] : 'руб.' ?>
                                        </div>
                                    <?php endif; ?>
                                </div>
                                <a href="#product_order" class="popup buy">Заказать установку</a>
                            </div>


                        <?php endforeach; ?>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                <?php endif; ?>
```

абсолютно ума не приложу, как дальше построить фильтр,перелопатил уйму статей, пока не могу въехать,буду рад любому пинку в нужном направлении

Answer (score 0):

Вы двигаетесь совсем не в ту сторону...

Вам нужно сделать ajax фильтр, для этого поместите весь html код в форму, в js передавайте выбранные значения в обработчик ВП, а в обработчике вставьте код php...

```
//это в function.php
function js_variables(){
$variables = array (
    'ajaxurl' => admin_url('admin-ajax.php')
);
    echo(
    '<script type="text/javascript">window.wp_data = 
    '.json_encode($variables).';</script>'
   );
}
add_action('wp_head','js_variables');

//это в файл где будет фильтр значения меняйте на свои
<form action="<?php echo site_url() ?>/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php" method="POST" id="filter">
    <select id="filterposts" name="sort_form" class="selectpicker change-list">
    <option value="значение">текст</option>
    <input type="hidden" name="action" value="myfilter">//значение myfilter передаем в functions можете написать любое имя позже увидите зачем
    </select>
</form>

//В functions.php
function true_filter_function(){
 //это обработчик что вам нужно вывести 
}
add_action('wp_ajax_myfilter <- ВОТ ЭТО СКРЫТОЕ ПОЛЕ', 'true_filter_function'); 
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_myfilter <- ВОТ ЭТО СКРЫТОЕ ПОЛЕ', 'true_filter_function');

//js 
$('#filter').change(function(){
            var filter = $(this);
            var info = filter.serialize();
            $.ajax({
                url:window.wp_data.ajaxurl,
                data:info,
                type:filter.attr('method'),
                success:function(data){
                    $('#topost').html(data);
                }
            });
        });
```

Все подсказки мои удалите, а к контейнеру где выводятся посты добавьте id topost и должно получится, обработчик php сами напишите там не тяжело юзайте query_posts и подставляйте свои аргументы

Comment: спасибо, буду пробовать. true_filter_function похоже не с блога truemisha? ))

Comment: и первый кусок кода понял в функции, второй, который форма в сам шаблон, а третий вместе со скриптом тоже в функции после первого объявления,верно?

Comment: да именно так...

Comment: спасибо, буду пробовать.